# Filter and sort results over multiple tables in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models Page and Post where Page can have multiple Posts. Users will be sharing multiple Posts per day with the same URL. As result I need to get feed of the most shared URL per day and it’s posts in the current day. Is there a way to do this in Django ORM?

```
class Page(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()

class Post(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(‘Page', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I ended up with this which gives me the most shared URL but now I can’t figure it out how to get all the related posts and have them sorted by `created_at`

```
Post.objects.filter(created_at__date=date.today()).values('page__id').annotate(num_shares=Count('page__id')).order_by('-num_shares')

<PostQuerySet [{'page__id': 2, 'num_shares': 6}, {'page__id': 1, 'num_shares': 5}]>
```

Comment: Check will this work for you `pubs = Post.objects.filter(created_at__date=date.today()).values('page__url','created_at').annotate(num_posts=Count('page__url'))'.order_by('created_at')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `Prefetch()` and [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to return a queryset of related objects.

You would do something like `pages = Page.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('post', queryset=Post.objects.filter(<date filter>), to_attr='posts'))`

You would then access page posts like

```
for page in pages:
    for post in page.posts:
```